# WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver unexpectedly exited on Raspberry-Pi with ChromeDriver and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver

I have written a python script that does some tasks in the browser (using Selenium), which works fine in Windows. Now I am trying to now get it onto my Raspberry Pi.

I did a lot of searching to find the best way to get this to work with Chromium. The best I could find was at this [Reddit Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/7341wt/success_how_to_run_selenium_chrome_webdriver_on/).

The problem is that I cannot find a chromedriver that jives with my version of Chromium (version 56.0.2924.84). And when I do apt-get upgrade it advises me that I have the newest version of Chromium. I've tried chromedriver versions 53 through 65 by downloading from this [Launchpad Link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/armhf/chromium-chromedriver).

So when I run the following

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver_path = 'usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
```

I get this error for chrome drivers > 58

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNoteCreatedException: Message: session not 
created exception: Chrome version must be >= 59.0.3071.0
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.43,platform=Linux 4.9.35-v7+ armv7l)
```

or this error for chrome drivers < 58

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 
Service /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

any help here would be appreciated

Comment: In case others get frustrated enough like me - I just ended up installing iceweasel and an older version of geckodriver and my script ended up working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question your **Chromium** binary is of **version 56.0.2924.84**. So keeping this constraint in consideration the solution would be to download either of the following **ChromeDriver** version from [**ChromeDriver Google Storage**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

- ChromeDriver v84: Supports Chrome v84
- ChromeDriver v83: Supports Chrome v83
- ChromeDriver v82: *Was intentionally skipped*
- ChromeDriver v81: Supports Chrome v81
- ChromeDriver v80: Supports Chrome v80
- ChromeDriver v79: Supports Chrome v79
- ChromeDriver v78: Supports Chrome v78
- ChromeDriver v77: Supports Chrome v77
- ChromeDriver v76: Supports Chrome v76
- ChromeDriver v75: Supports Chrome v75
- ChromeDriver v74: Supports Chrome v74
- ChromeDriver v73: Supports Chrome v73
- ChromeDriver v2.46: Supports Chrome v71-73
- ChromeDriver v2.46: Supports Chrome v71-73
- ChromeDriver v2.45: Supports Chrome v70-72
- ChromeDriver v2.44: Supports Chrome v69-71 (same as ChromeDriver 2.43, but with additional bug fixes)
- ChromeDriver v2.43: Supports Chrome v69-71
- ChromeDriver v2.42: Supports Chrome v68-70
- ChromeDriver v2.41: Supports Chrome v67-69
- ChromeDriver v2.40: Supports Chrome v66-68
- ChromeDriver v2.39: Supports Chrome v66-68
- ChromeDriver v2.38: Supports Chrome v65-67
- ChromeDriver v2.37: Supports Chrome v64-66
- ChromeDriver v2.36: Supports Chrome v63-65
- ChromeDriver v2.35: Supports Chrome v62-64
- ChromeDriver v2.34: Supports Chrome v61-63
- ChromeDriver v2.33: Supports Chrome v60-62
- ChromeDriver v2.32: Supports Chrome v59-61
- ChromeDriver v2.31: Supports Chrome v58-60
- ChromeDriver v2.30: Supports Chrome v58-60
- ChromeDriver v2.29: Supports Chrome v56-58
- ChromeDriver v2.28: Supports Chrome v55-57
- ChromeDriver v2.27: Supports Chrome v54-56

> **Note**: A few months ago, *Chromium Team* made a [preliminary announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/HvlKWqv34es) that ChromeDriver's versioning model will be changing. *Chromium Team* is moving forward with the plan. Specifically, ChromeDriver 2.46 will be the last release carrying the major version of 2. Future ChromeDriver releases will carry a version number similar to Chrome release. We will start with a release of ChromeDriver 73 next week, before the Beta release of Chrome 73.

Here is how the new release model will work:

- ChromeDriver will be using the same version number scheme as Chrome. See https://www.chromium.org/developers/version-numbers for more details.
- Each version of ChromeDriver will support Chrome with matching major, minor, and build version numbers. For example, upcoming ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.* will support all Chrome versions that start with 73.0.3683.
- Before a new major version of Chrome goes to Beta, a matching version of ChromeDriver will be released. For example, a new version of ChromeDriver will be release next week to match the Beta release of Chrome m73.
- After the initial release of a new major version, we will release patches as needed. These patches may or may not coincide with updates to Chrome.

---

### ChromeDriver for Raspberry Pi

As you are using **Raspberry Pi** you need to download the **arm** format of *ChromeDriver* from this [link](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v1.6.0/chromedriver-v2.21-linux-armv7l.zip) and use it within your program.

---

### Additional Considerations

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* as per the above discussion.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v56.x*** levels. (as per the discussion)
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: thanks for the info. Its very well done and will help me or others down the line. I ended up getting frustrated enough where I installed iceweasel and geckodriver and it worked out in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Before: You should download binary chromedriver, unzip it somewhere in you PC and set path to this driver like this:

```py
webdriver.Chrome('/home/user/drivers/chromedriver')

ChromeDriverManager(path=custom_path).install()
```

It’s boring!!! Moreover every time the new version of driver released, you should go and repeat all steps again and again.

With webdriver manager, you just need to do two simple steps:

Install manager:

```sh
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Use with Chrome:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Use with Chromium:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.utils import ChromeType

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install())
```

Use with FireFox:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

Use with IE:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import IEDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Ie(IEDriverManager().install())
```

Use with Edge:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
```

Use with Opera:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.opera import OperaDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=OperaDriverManager().install())
```

#### Note

If the Opera browser is installed in a location other than `C:/Program Files` or `C:/Program Files (x86)` on windows and `/usr/bin/opera` for all unix variants and mac, then use the below code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.opera import OperaDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('allow-elevated-browser')
options.binary_location = "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\FOLDERLOCATION\\Opera\\VERSION\\opera.exe"
driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=OperaDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

Comment: By far the best answer yet on selenium installation