# Is Chrome installation needed or only chromedriver when using Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I've tried to search, but haven't found a definitive answer. On Windows Server 2016 WITHOUT Chrome Browser actually installed. I downloaded the correct "chromedriver.exe" and placed it in "D:\Apps\chromedriver.exe". I have added to my environment PATH the full path as "D:\Apps\chromedriver.exe".

When I attempt to start my Windows Service that utilizes the latest Selenium, I get the following error:

```
Exception occurred: Failed initializing web driver: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Question: Do I have to actually install the full-blown browser in addition to the chromedriver, or is this simply just not finding the chromedriver.exe in my Python code (included below for full disclosure):

```
def __init__(self, username, password, environment='cert'):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.environment = environment

    # Instantiate a chrome options object so you can set the size and headless preference
    self.chrome_options = Options()

    # Toggle Headless or not
    if HEADLESS_TOGGLE == 1:
        self.chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

    self.chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")  # Disables "Lost UI Shared Context GPU Error on Windows"
    self.chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')  # Disables Extensions
    self.chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-software-rasterizer")  # Disables "Lost UI Shared Context GPU Error on Windows"
    self.chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1024x768")
    self.chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")  # Errors Only
    self.chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")  # Keeps history and logs clear
    self.chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    self.chrome_options.add_argument("--mute_audio")  # No loud surprises!
    self.chrome_options.add_argument("--no-gpu")  # Disables gpu-based errors (headless)

    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=self.chrome_options)
```

Comment: Yes you do need a full-install of the browser, for example see the Selenium docs for Chrome "`The server expects you to have Chrome installed in the default location for each system...`" src: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. That needs to contain the location of the complete full-blown browser standalone installation.

Comment: The selenium driver acts as a wrapper to the full browser: "The ChromeDriver consists of three separate pieces. There is the browser itself ("chrome"), the language bindings provided by the Selenium project ("the driver") and an executable downloaded from the Chromium project which acts as a bridge between "chrome" and the "driver". This executable is called "chromedriver"", which is similar for all browsers. src: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#view-all-chromedriver-downloads

Comment: Ah ok, great. Thank you for the clarification. I appreciate the information @davedwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users provided relevant link to confirm that, "YES" a full Chrome installation is needed in addition to the actual chromedriver.

Link: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Answer (score 15):

This error message...

```
Exception occurred: Failed initializing web driver: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to find the *Chrome binary* while trying to initiate a new new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

As per the documentation with in the wiki page of [ChromeDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver):

- [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) is a standalone server which earlier implemented the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871)'s [wire protocol](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/SeleniumHQ/selenium/JsonWireProtocol.md) but slowly and gradually shifting it's implementation as per [WebDriver standard](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/chromedriver_status.md).
- The ChromeDriver consists of three separate pieces.

  - There is the browser itself i.e. *chrome*
  - The language bindings provided by the Selenium project i.e. *the driver*
  - An executable downloaded from the [Chromium project](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) which acts as a bridge between `chrome` and the `driver` which is called **`chromedriver`** and we refer to it as the `server`.
- In generic scenarios the `server` expects you to have *Chrome* installed in the default location for each system:

  - **Linux**: */usr/bin/google-chrome* <sup>1</sup>
  - **Mac**: */Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome*
  - **Windows XP**: *%HOMEPATH%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe*
  - **Windows Vista and newer**: *C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe*

**Note**: <sup>1</sup>: For Linux systems, the ChromeDriver expects /usr/bin/google-chrome to be a symlink to the actual Chrome binary.

> You can find a detailed discussion on overriding the default *Chrome binary location* in [WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary error with Selenium in Python for older versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-find-chrome-binary-error-with-selenium/50140554#50140554)

---

### Solution

So ideally to execute your tests using *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome* combo you need to:

- Install the full-blown [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browser.
- Download the compatible version of `chromedriver.exe`
- [Quick installation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#quick-installation) of *ChromeDriver*:

  - **Mac users with Homebrew**: `brew tap homebrew/cask && brew cask install chromedriver`
  - **Debian based Linux distros**: `sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver`
  - **Windows users with Chocolatey installed**: `choco install chromedriver`
- You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

  - [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)
  - [Selenium for ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser and the log message “Only local connections are allowed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547360/selenium-for-chromedriver-and-chrome-browser-and-the-log-message-only-local-con/48551748#48551748)
  - [WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver unexpectedly exited on Raspberry-Pi with ChromeDriver and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796818/webdriverexception-message-service-usr-lib-chromium-browser-chromedriver-unex/49799791#49799791)

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary error with Selenium in Python for older versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-find-chrome-binary-error-with-selenium/50140554#50140554)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using PowerShell. I figured out that you need to put the correct `chromedriver.exe` version, according to the installed Chrome browser, in the path under Selenium Module installation folder, and replace the existing file.

Check this answer for details:

[I cannot start chrome instant using PowerShell and Selenium module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70990586/i-cannot-start-chrome-instant-using-powershell-and-selenium-module)