# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I'm facing an error on linux platform initializing Google Chrome.

Method 'inicializaChrome' threw exception. Nested exception is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

I used sugestions, that didn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) binary was unable to find the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) binary while inititiating a session.

---

### Details

This error can be observed in a couple of cases as follows:

- Possibly you don't have *Google Chrome* installed in your system. In that case you have to install *Google Chrome* as a mandatory measure.
- *Google Chrome* is installed in a non-standard location. In that case you have to pass the absolute path of the *Google Chrome* binary through the `setBinary()` method as follows:

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.setBinary(/path/to/chrome);
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Is Chrome installation needed or only chromedriver when using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62449076/7429447)
- [WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary error with Selenium in Python for older versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50140554/7429447)