# Launch application URL using selenium WebDriver. but after run the Java application shows error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

After Setup the Selenium WebDriver I want to launch the application URL through chrome browser, but it's show error.

```
SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J(W): Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J(W): Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary 
Host info: host: 'USER-PC', ip: '192.168.1.32'
Build info: version: '4.16.1', revision: '9b4c83354e'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.9'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}]}]
```

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76847943/23182657) answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843959/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-could-not-start-a-new-session-r)