# Website behavior in Chrome instance launched using ChromeDriver is not same as in regular Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am preparing a simple cucumber/selenium based application which launches a new browser, brings on the login page of Target.com and attempts to login.

I was able to bring up the Target website home page, traverse to login page and fill up credentials. But the button click on "Sign In" was not working. Just to see the behavior, i tried manually logging in to Target website(in the browser launched by the application) using the credentials and noticed, the "Sign In" button does not work. If i launch Chrome regularly as an independent application, it works.

I checked that JS is enabled in the Chrome launched using ChromeDriver. What else could be an issue? The website url is : https://www.target.com (click on Sign In on top right followed by Sign In in the menu to bring login page. The "Sign in" button on the login page is the one giving problem)

Using the following:
ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.20
Chrome Application Version: 74.0.3729.169

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to instantiate a driver navigate to the login url and do a click to the login button and it works correctly.

Probably your currently chromedriver (73.0.3683.20) can't automate your chrome version (74.0.3729.169) try to upgrade the chromedriver and be aware that chrome updates automatically

UPDATE:
Just checked chromedriver doc and your chromedriver version only works form chrome 73
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Issue :** Your Chrome Browser Version is 74 and Your framework is having **ChromeDriver Binary v73.0.3683.20** which supports **Chrome Browser v73**

**Solution :** Update your ChromeDriver Binary Version to v74.0.3729.6

Please have a look at **Chrome Browser Release Section :** [Chrome Browser vs ChromeDriver Binary](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and follow below information -

- If you are using *Chrome version 75*, please download [ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.8/)
- If you are using *Chrome version 74*, please download [ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/) **(You shall follow this)**
- If you are using *Chrome version 73*, please download [ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=73.0.3683.68/)
- For older version of *Chrome*, please see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796818/webdriverexception-message-service-usr-lib-chromium-browser-chromedriver-unex/49799791#49799791) for the version of ChromeDriver that supports it.

Hope following above would resolve your issue.

Comment: Based on what the OP stated, this would have to be the correct answer, but I don't know why they are even able to enter login credentials.  When I encountered this problem (Chrome updated itself without my knowledge) it told me specifically that this was the problem and the browser would not even open until I updated the driver.

Comment: Totally agree with you.

Comment: If there is mismatch between chromedriver binary and browser version, then we would not be able to perform any action with in browser itself as before browser would not get launched