# Selenium driven ChromeDriver can't find Chrome binary

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I just uninstalled Chrome because it was acting strange (fixed now) and after this Selenium in Python is not able to identify the Chrome driver binary, which is extremely strange because it should be completely unaffected and it is in a different location and a different version from the chrome I use on my desktop, code is as follows and has worked for years now.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--load-extension='+exension_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_folder,options=chrome_options)
```

Anyone has any idea what on earth is going on? I get the follow error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.40*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.40*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v66-68**

- As you have uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled presumably you are using the latest *chrome=85.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v85.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/85.0.4183.87/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 85**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.40* and the *Chrome Browser v85.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v85.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=85.0.4183.87/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 85.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v85.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/85.0.4183.87/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Is there anyway to download the old chrome browser for v66-68? I have a ton of scripts that is running off that version of chrome and would greatly prefer not to muddle this too much

Comment: @nonein Tough call, even if are able to install any older version of chrome updater will update it in a short while.

Comment: Yeah but thats what I dont get because the other chrome I had was working fine? Was that because I never updated it? Would I not be able to point the driver towards a chrome version that was different?

Comment: @nonein You are right, presumably the Chrome wasn't updated manually or the updater was modified. You need to match [ChromeDriver-Chrome versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547360/selenium-for-chromedriver-and-chrome-browser-and-the-log-message-only-local-con/48551748#48551748) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796818/chromedriver-not-working-on-raspberry-pi-for-use-with-chromium-and-selenium/49799791#49799791)

Comment: additional question in regards to the above, my laptop runs Chrome 85 as well and can use the "old" webdriver, additionally, the old webdriver executes mouse movements MUCH faster than the new driver, factor 10x or so, is there any reason why the driver can run on one computer but not the other even though they use the same version of Chrome?

Comment: @nonein Let us discuss this in [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium)

Answer (score 1):

Automatically get the chrome binary path depending upon your OS:

This function checks the current operating system using platform.system() and returns the expected path to the Chrome binary.

It handles default Chrome locations on:

- Darwin (MacOS)
- Linux
- Windows

If the OS is not one of the above, an exception is raised.

The return value can be used to set the binary_location in
Selenium's ChromeOptions.

```
import platform

def get_chrome_binary():
  # Check the operating system and set the Chrome binary path accordingly
  if platform.system() == "Darwin":  # macOS
      binary_location = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
  elif platform.system() == "Linux":  # Linux-based system (e.g., Ubuntu Docker container)
      binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
  elif platform.system() == "Windows":  # Windows
      # Provide the path to the Chrome executable on Windows
      binary_location = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'  # Adjust the path as needed
  else:
      raise Exception("Unsupported operating system")  # You can handle other OSes based on your requirements
  
  return binary_location
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a clean code and to stop track the chrome path/version, I recommend to you to use [webdriver_manager](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager)

Install it

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

and use it like this

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--load-extension='+exension_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

but if don't want to use it here is the code for local browser

```
chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument('--load-extension='+exension_path)
chrome_options.binary_location = 'YOUR_PATH'  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath(“chromedriver"),   chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

but I totally recommend using the first version.

Comment: the Options(), what library is that from? If I exclude the chrome_options = Options() then I still get the following error: WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: Selenium Options - from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options