# Chrome prompting sign in

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Suddenly today when attempt to locally run tests, chrome has been prompting me to sign in to chrome for use when launching via the ChromeWebdriver. Currently hittting this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZaLX.jpg

This is in Windows using Chrome. It was previously working fine, today it has started to ask this. Unsure if this is due to a new version of chrome but it is likely an option that needs to be turned on / off.

```
            {
                var options = GetChromeOptions();
                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            }
```

etc etc

```
    private static ChromeOptions GetChromeOptions()
    {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        // From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518159/unable-to-open-chrome-browser-using-selenium-webdriver-loading-unpacked-extensi
        chromeOptions.AddArguments("disable-extensions");
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseSelenoid"].ToLower() != "true")
        {
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--start-maximized");

            var chromeVersion = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChromeVersion"];
            if (chromeVersion != null && chromeVersion.Length > 0)
            {
                chromeOptions.BrowserVersion = chromeVersion;
            }
        }

        return chromeOptions;
    }
```

Instead of hitting a chrome sign in, I should hit a new window of chrome.

Comment: are you using maven?

Comment: it actually turned out to be an IT whitelisting issue (nothing fixable on my end.)