# Could not load extension from scoped_dir6312_32763/internal.Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator with ChromeDriver Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-automation-extension

I have created a project using vue-cli 3 which automatically set up e2ed tests for me. When I try to run the tests, I get a popup from chrome, telling me that "Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator".

This seems to be a common problem, one solution offered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518159/unable-to-open-chrome-browser-using-selenium-webdriver-loading-unpacked-extensi) is

```
ChromeOptions o = new ChromeOptions();
o.addArguments("disable-extensions");
o.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(o);
```

Now this is Java code, but I assume there's a way to achieve the same thing in a vue.js project. However, I have no idea where to put this configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This popup:

[image: extension_error]

with the error message as...

```
Error Loading Extension
Failed to load extension from: 'C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6312_32763\internal'. Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator.
OK
```

...implies that an extension has not been loaded as it is disabled by the administrator.

---

As per the discussion [Failed to load extention from: ... Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1749) *ChromeDriver* uses *Chrome automation extension* for automating various functions like window sizing, window positioning, etc.

The **Failed to load extension..** popup means that this extension has not been loaded. If you manually close the popup, browser will act normally and *ChromeDriver* commands will continue to work as expected. But in this case if you try executing window resizing or window re-positioning commands, it will throw an error as **`unknown error: cannot get automation extension`**.

---

### Background

Till *ChromeDriver v2.28* whenever an organizations admin policy forbidden extensions, to bypass the restriction users have used the argument `disable-extensions` as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

and it worked perfecto.

*ChromeDriver v2.28* onwards, whenever `disable-extensions` flag is passed by test, *ChromeDriver* implicitly passes **`disable-extensions-except`** flag which in turn loads *Chrome automation extension*. This extension helps Chromedriver to perform window sizing and window re-positioning operations.

So, if your organizational admin policy blocks extensions, display of popup **Failed to load extension from: ... Loading of unpacked extensions** is an expected behavior.

This issue had a dependency on [Selenium support for headless](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604324).

---

### Work around

As an alternative, you can set the **`useAutomationExtension`** capability to `false` as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This capability inturn will help to not load *Chrome Automation extension* and **`Failed to load extension`** popup would not appear. But you will not be able to perform any window resizing/positioning operations without the *Chrome automation extension*.

Now, [Selenium support for headless](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604324) being resolved *ChromeDriver* will no longer require this extension and you shouldn't have seen this error/popup.

### Solution

The simplest solution would be to use the latest version of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome* combination among either of the following:

- If you are using **Chrome version 73**, please download **`ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.20`**
- If you are using **Chrome version 72**, please download **`ChromeDriver 2.46`** or **`ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69`**
- If you are using **Chrome version 71**, please download **`ChromeDriver 2.46`** or **`ChromeDriver 71.0.3578.137`**
- For older version of Chrome, please see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796818/webdriverexception-message-service-usr-lib-chromium-browser-chromedriver-unex/49799791#49799791).

### Alternative

Some other alternatives are:

- Add the *Registry Key* `ExtensionInstallWhitelist` to whitelist
- Remove the *Registry Key* `ExtensionInstallBlacklist` containing a string key **1** with value **`*`**

Comment: Thank you @DebanjanB, removing the registry key ExtensionInstallBlacklist solved the problem for now (though I wouldn't be surprised if it was reinstalled by some group policy in the future). Regarding the different configuration options (ChromeOptions ...) I still have no idea where to put them in my vue.js project. Do you have any hints for me?

Comment: @smeier_ec Nothing more substantial as of now. But if I come across any relevant documentation or whitepaper, I will update the answer and update you through a comment.