# How to disable ALL chrome extensions using chromedriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-automation-extension

After upgrading to chromedriver 74 noticed odd extensions behaviour on Windows. 
Is it possible to switch ALL extensions off?

1. Start chromedriver

```sh
chromedriver --log-level=ALL
```

2. Create session with extensions DISABLED

```sh
curl -d '{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--disable-extensions"]}}}' http://localhost:9515/session
```

Some dev tool extension is loaded

> [1558606783.990][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-extensions --disable-extensions-except="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir19964_411\internal" --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --force-fieldtrials=SiteIsolationExtensions/Control --ignore-certificate-errors --log-level=0 --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir19964_22650" data:,

Note

> --disable-extensions-except="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir19964_411\internal"

Is there a way to get rid of it? Did not find any clues in chromedriver docs, those are extremely sketchy.

Comment: There's a way to fool chromedriver - pass some other param along with --disable-extensions (separated by space), e.g. simply repeat it "--disable-extensions --disable-extensions". It works, but bit ugly.

Comment: Turns out it is not something new - found the same issue in chromedriver 2.36

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54594305/could-not-load-extension-from-scoped-dir6312-32763-internal-loading-of-unpacked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571119/loading-of-unpacked-extensions-is-disabled-by-the-administrator

Comment: since Chromedriver v2.28 - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1749#c5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Set `chromeOptions.useAutomationExtension` to false, it will prevent injecting of Chrome Automation Extension

```
{
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "goog:chromeOptions": {
      "useAutomationExtension": false,
      "args": [
        "--disable-extensions"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Long version

Automation Extension flag is not mentioned in `chromedriver` docs http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities, but can be traced in [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/capabilities.cc?type=cs&q=useAutomationExtension&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=579) for current version (75.0.)

```
    parser_map["useAutomationExtension"] =
        base::Bind(&ParseBoolean, &capabilities->use_automation_extension);
```

```
    status = internal::ProcessExtensions(
        capabilities.extensions, extension_dir->GetPath(),
        capabilities.use_automation_extension, &switches, extension_bg_pages);
```

```
  if (include_automation_extension) {
    ...
    if (switches->HasSwitch("disable-extensions")) {
      UpdateExtensionSwitch(switches, "disable-extensions-except",
                            automation_extension.value());
```

As mentioned in [54594305](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571119/loading-of-unpacked-extensions-is-disabled-by-the-administrator) Java code using selenium driver would be

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
```