# Protractor webdriver-manager chromedriver update

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

There seems to be a issue with chromedriver 2.2 and the newest version of Chrome. This issue has to deal with the protractor not being able to send tab keys with 2.2. If I do webdriver-manager update, it does not update to the chromedriver 2.4. I did a hack where I downloaded chromedriver 2.4 exe myself and manually put it in the selenium folder, but that is not the best way to do this. How do you update  protractor to use the latest version of Chromedriver 2.4?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What version of Protractor are you using? Have you tried upgrading it to the latest version?

Comment: Yes, but let make sure to do it again. I will do it on a clean machine. Also I updated my question to be a question. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having the same issue as you. It is related to a new release of chrome 54.

You need to wait for the next release of webdriver-manager (it was promised to be today), have look at https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/102.

I guess in the mean time you can update your webdriver manually (the fix is already in the master branch, it was just not published yet with a version tag).

Hope I helped.

Comment: @Maccurt how did you update webdriver-manager? Each time I run the command `webdriver-manager update` it just tells me *selenium standalone is up to date. chromedriver is up to date.*

Comment: I re-installed webdriver-managerwith npm, that should update you to the latest one..

Answer (score 7):

To update protractor version globally and webdriver-manager run below commands in console.

`npm update protractor -g`

`webdriver-manager update`

If still the latest protractor is not having the latest chromedriver then to update it manually follow these below steps

enter latest chromedriver version in file config.json this file is present under path '/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built'

optional (and change 'mac32' to 'mac64' in file 'chrome_driver.js' which is present under path /webdriver-manager/built/lib/binaries)

run `webdriver-manager update` in the console.

**hint**: To get the path of 'webdriver-manager' folder observe the console after command `webdriver-manager update`

Comment: Had an issue with latest version of chrome breaking my selenium tests, yet running `webdriver-manager update` did not bump the version number, but your tip bout updating the config.json and then running that command fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

Inorder to run protractor in google chrome versions greater than  57 we need Chrome driver version greater than or equal to 2.28.

With the latest version of protractor I  had Chrome driver version of 2.27

Inorder to update the chromedriver to specific version I used the following commands

`webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.28`

`webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome 2.28`

If it does not work after updating try to change the chrome driver version to `"chromedriver": "2.28"` in the 
following path 
nodeJs\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\config.json

Comment: `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 73.0.3683.68` did the magic for Chrome 73

Answer (score 1):

First unhid your hidden files.

Go to this path for mac user, usr/local/lib/node_modules, you should only see the protractor folder(which should have webdriver-manager already), if you see a separate folder for webdriver-manager or webdriver, move those to trash.

Now go to usr/bin, navigate to your webdriver-manager file and delete it.

Run sudo npm install -g protractor, and then start your webdriver server, last step do "sudo webdriver-manager update".

Now you should be able to invoke your browser :)

Answer (score 1):

I did npm uninstall chromedriver
and then
npm install chromedriver update --versions.chrome=78.0.3904.108

78.0.3904.108 is latest chrome version installed for me

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
npm i chromedriver --chromedriver_version=LATEST
npm uninstall protractor & npm install --save-dev protractor
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when chrome was recently updated and even after updating chrome driver, my binaries were just not getting updated. Reinstalling protractor globally instantly worked for me.