# How to config chromdrive to download in protractor?

Tags: angular, selenium-chromedriver, protractor, e2e

I got error of chromedriver version is only support google chrom version 100.

My current google chrome is 109

```
Current browser version is 109.0.5414.119 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

```
[13:12:27] I/file_manager - creating folder /home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
[13:12:27] I/config_source - curl -o/home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
[13:12:28] I/downloader - curl -o/home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_100.0.4896.20.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/100.0.4896.60/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[13:12:28] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_100.0.4896.20.zip
[13:12:29] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_100.0.4896.20
[13:12:30] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:12:30] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[13:12:30] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 100
Current browser version is 109.0.5414.119 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
  (Driver info: chromedriver=100.0.4896.60 (6a5d10861ce8de5fce22564658033b43cb7de047-refs/branch-heads/4896@{#875}),platform=Linux 5.10.0-19-cloud-amd64 x86_64)
[13:12:30] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 100
Current browser version is 109.0.5414.119 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
  (Driver info: chromedriver=100.0.4896.60 (6a5d10861ce8de5fce22564658033b43cb7de047-refs/branch-heads/4896@{#875}),platform=Linux 5.10.0-19-cloud-amd64 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at /home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at /home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29
    at _fulfilled (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at /home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/qkFs1r9o/0/root/front/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[13:12:30] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

How can i specific version of chromedrive to download?
This is my protractor config:

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800x600", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--disable-extensions"]
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

Specific version of chromedrive to download with protractor

Comment: Did you search stack overflow? This issue occurs quite often because webdrivers have to match the chrome browser version exactly and have to be updated manually. See e.g.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823677/protractor-webdriver-manager-chromedriver-update

Answer (score 0):

***The error:***

```
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 100
Current browser version is 109.0.5414.119 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

***Solution***

In your case the installed version of Chrome is `109.0.5414.119,` but the `ChromeDriver` only supports up to `version 100`. To resolve the issue, you should upgrade your `ChromeDriver` to a version that supports Chrome `109.0.5414.119` or downgrade your Google Chrome to `version 100`.

URL for `chromeDriver` is [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path)

Comment: But I am using ansible to install chrome on a VM and run e2e on gitlab-ci, so have no opiton install them manually

Comment: You can use role in Ansible to install `Google Chrome` and `ChromeDriver`

Comment: - name: Install chromedriver
      shell: cd /tmp/; wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/109.0.5414.74/chromedriver_linux64.zip; unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip; mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
      become: true

    - name: Install google-chrome
      shell: wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
      become: true

Comment: I have added it in ansible script

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Yeah, it is always the same error

Comment: the webdriver-manager automatic download chromedriver ver-100 by default, have any change to config protractor to specific  the version (109 ) of chromedriver which i want to install?
Or a url for isntall google-chrome version 100?

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Install chromedriver
      shell: cd /tmp/; wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/109.0.5414.74/chromedriver_linux64.zip; unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip; mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
      become: true

    - name: Install google-chrome
      shell: wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
      become: true
```