# Google Chrome V 57.0 unable to input text when used with Robot Framework & throws error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework for test automation.
Recently I upgraded my Chrome browser to the latest version, V 57.0
Since then, I am unable to execute my test scripts on Chrome.
The webpage opens up and navigates until Login page, the cursor focus is set on Username field and then it just keeps on trying for few seconds until i receive an error saying:

```
 [ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on
   failure: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot get
   automation extension from unknown error: page could not be found:
   chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
   (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)   (Driver info:
   chromedriver=2.24.417431
   (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT
   10.0.10586 x86_64)
```

I have no extensions installed in the browser.

Also followed up a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506731/google-chrome-unable-to-navigate-to-specified-url-when-triggered-from-selenium)
It just mentions about removing your extensions, which I already did.

Thanks

Comment: Be sure you have the latest Chromedriver (2.28)

Comment: Yup, that worked :)
Sorry, but read your comment now.
Cheers

Comment: I thought so after thinking about it more.  I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Always make certain you are using current and compatible versions of Chromedriver.  I always suspect this when the problems show up at the element level.  The driver has to be updated a lot as the browser evolves.  In your case, you've indicated a current Chromedriver is a solution.  Note that this solution generalizes to all browsers.

If the problem were more related to window sizing/resizing, it might be due to the fact that selenium is trying to use an extension to perform a windowing function.  [Issues with running headless...](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/headless-dev/VytKt327v2I)  This assumes you are running headless.

Solution is likely to rework the test for headless runs, or run else try a real browser.

Comment: I could see the browser opening and doing the actions as per the test script until login page, so I am sure it is not running headless.
Though I updated the chromedriver.exe and replaced the old chromedriver.exe file located under C:\Python27\Lib with the new one and that worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your chromedriver is not latest as said in your error message (Driver info:  chromedriver=2.24.417431). [Latest available chromedriver version is V2.28](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Use latest available Chrome Drivers and you will be all good.

Mark +1 if this answer is useful to you.